# How to define user's locale in angularJS

Tags: angularjs

I want to set date values as per user's locale. But I am not sure how to check user's locale in angularJS. I dont want to use normal Jquery/Javasciprt way.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use this line of code:

```
window.navigator.language
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks link13 but How to update date format as per user's locale then?

Comment: That is automatic when you do new Date(dateInUTCFormat)

Comment: As far as setting date formats, etc, I'd recommend this library: [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/). It may be overkill for your needs, but it's pretty great in terms of dates, and has a version that includes locales (with different languages).